# Why does function boot return values of different types than those from the statistic used inside boot?

Tags: r, function, machine-learning, bootstrap-4

I'm running the classification method **Bagging Tree (Bootstrap Aggregation)** and compare this misclassification error rate with one from one single tree.

It's strange to me because the function `estim.pred` returns a matrix of factors that map to "pos" and "neg", but `res.boot$t` returns a matrix of integers taking on the values of 1 or 2, where as `estim.pred` is the statistic of `res.boot$t`.

Could you please explain the reason for this phenomenon?

```
library(rpart)
library(boot)
library(mlbench)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

n <- 768
ntrain <- 468
ntest <- 300
B <- 100
M <- 100
train.error <- vector(length = M)
test.error <- vector(length = M)
bagging.error <- vector(length = M)

estim.pred <- function(a.sample, vector.of.indices)
      {
      current.train <- a.sample[vector.of.indices, ]
      current.fitted.model <- rpart(diabetes ~ ., data = current.train, method = "class")
      predict(current.fitted.model, test.set, type = "class")
      }

fitted.tree <- rpart(diabetes ~ ., data = train.set, method = "class")
pred.train <- predict(fitted.tree, train.set, type = "class")
res.boot = boot(train.set, estim.pred, B)

head(pred.train)
head(res.boot$t)
```

> [image]

Comment: `res.boot$t` is a matrix. A matrix cannot contain a factor variable. Thus, the matrix contains the underlying integer values. Transpose the matrix, turn it into a data.frame and turn the integers into factor variables with your levels.

Comment: @Roland you meant the integer returned from `res.boot$t` corresponds to the rank of the factor in the alphabet order, right?

Comment: Yes, compare with `unclass(head(pred.train))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is @Roland comment. I post it here to remove my question from unanswered list.

> `res.boot$t` is a matrix. A matrix cannot contain a factor variable. Thus, the matrix contains the underlying integer values. Transpose the matrix, turn it into a data.frame and turn the integers into factor variables with your levels.